# How to detect events in modal by keymap

Tags: python, operator, keymap

Root problem: I have a modal for the 3DView where I want to allow users to use any 3DView navigation input (pan, zoom, FPS walk) via `{PASS_THROUGH}` but no other input. However, I'd rather not just limit by saying whether they pressed a specific button but if they did a specific event, such as Set 3D Cursor. Users may remap or add new keymaps for navigation, and I'd like to be able to support that.

I know the `event` parameter available to `modal()` have keymap properties, but doesn't seem to have the identifier itself (shown in the preferences below), but please correct me if I'm wrong. Is there an example of someone matching `event`s in `modal()` via identifier? If that's not possible, is there an example of determining if an event in `modal()` falls under one of these keymaps?

[image: Blender Preferences 3D view keymap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"X Y"'s answer is great, it does answer the question, definitely worth the upvote. Thankfully I found an existing Blender API function that does the heavy lifting: [bpy.types.KeyMapItems.match_event](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyMapItems.html?highlight=match_event#bpy.types.KeyMapItems.match_event). When given an event (which `modal()` has as a parameter), `match_event` returns a matching `KeyMapItem`, which includes the id name. Using that, I could compare and validate if the `KeyMapItem` is under 3D View by just checking the id's prefix. I'll use the other answer's great modal example as a template:

```py
import bpy


class MY_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.my_operator"
    bl_label = "Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC':    return {'FINISHED'}
        for kc in context.window_manager.keyconfigs:
            for km in kc.keymaps:
                found_keymap = km.keymap_items.match_event(event)
                if found_keymap is not None and found_keymap.idname.startswith('view3d'):
                    print('Found keymap:', found_keymap.idname)
                    return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


addon_keymaps = []
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OP)

    # Add the hotkey
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.my_operator", type='F9', value='PRESS', ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OP)

    # Remove the hotkey
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2):

Operator shortcut: **Ctrl F9**
End Operator: **Esc**

```
import bpy

#all_region_type = {'WINDOW', 'HEADER', 'CHANNELS', 'TEMPORARY', 'UI', 'TOOLS', 'TOOL_PROPS', 'PREVIEW', 'HUD', 'NAVIGATION_BAR', 'EXECUTE', 'FOOTER', 'TOOL_HEADER', 'XR'}

def find_km(kcs, name = "3D View", allow_region_type = {}, op = "view3d.cursor3d"):
    key_list = []
    for kc in kcs:
        for ks in kc.keymaps:
            if ks.region_type in allow_region_type:
                for k in ks.keymap_items:
                    if k.active:
                        if k.idname == op:
                            key_list.append(k)
    return key_list


class MY_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.my_operator"
    bl_label = "Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.keys_set_cursor = find_km(bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs, "3D View", {'WINDOW'}, "view3d.cursor3d")

        for k in self.keys_set_cursor:
            print(k.idname, k.type, k.any, k.shift, k.ctrl, k.alt, k.oskey, k.value, k.key_modifier)

        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC':    return {'FINISHED'}
        if self.is_key_trigger(self.keys_set_cursor, event):
            print("PASS_THROUGH")
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
        else:
            print("RUNNING_MODAL")
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    # Not support key_modifier
    def is_key_trigger(self, keys, evt):
        for k in keys:
            if k.value == evt.value:
                if k.type == evt.type:
                    if k.any:
                        if evt.shift or evt.ctrl or evt.alt or evt.oskey:
                            return True
                    elif evt.shift == k.shift and evt.ctrl == k.ctrl and evt.alt == k.alt and evt.oskey == k.oskey:
                        return True
        return False


addon_keymaps = []
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OP)

    # Add the hotkey
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.my_operator", type='F9', value='PRESS', ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OP)

    # Remove the hotkey
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you, great modal example to use! I did find an existing function that does most of the heavy lifting for this. But this is a solid answer, I appreciate it.