# Allow viewport manipulation during move command via script

Tags: python

**EDIT**

**I've moved a different way. Using ray_cast to get face location and normal. Applying the normal to the empty vector is now my challenge :)**

**EDIT**

I'm writing an addon that I need to interactively move an empty and have it snap and align to any face the mouse runs over, exactly like the `move` command with snapping active, I'd also like the user to be able to manipulate the viewport during this but `bpy.ops.transform.translate("INVOKE_DEFAULT")` does not allow this behavior.

I thought I could run `bpy.ops.transform.translate("INVOKE_DEFAULT")` then kill it on a `MIDDLEMOUSE` `PRESS` event in my modal (like when pressing `ESC`), then start it again on a `MIDDLEMOUSE` `RELEASE` event. 2 problems with this, I can't find a way to terminate the translate operator from code (despite many hours searching) and if it's started from within my modal the events don't seem to get passed through anymore, I'm assuming because it runs as a modal and running modals from modals is not a good idea.

Is there a way to force `bpy.ops.transform.translate("INVOKE_DEFAULT")` to allow viewport manipulation explicitly? Or would I have to make my own operator? (no idea even where to start with the snapping bit)

How do you terminate a `bpy.ops` (that's running as a modal) from code?

Is there another way?

Comment: The common idea is `return {'PASS_THROUGH'}` in operator when pan/rotate/scale viewport, otherwise `return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}`   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259016/how-to-detect-events-in-modal-by-keymap/259472#259472

Comment: Thanks @XY
This is how I have my modal set up. The problem is if I start `bpy.ops.transform.translate("INVOKE_DEFAULT")` from within my modal, the events stop being passed through

Comment: If `bpy.ops.transform.translate` modal is running, it can't run another operator modal until it finish. Also should be avoid to use `ops` in operator.

Comment: Yep, this is my problem. Do you know how to force an ops to terminate via code?

Comment: No, it can't force an ops to terminate as it will cause issue/bugs in some cases unless the ops has this capability. I don't think most build-in ops have this feature.